# System.Data.SQLite and Fluent NHibernate - IDBCommand could not be found

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, .net-4.0, fluent-nhibernate, 64-bit

I am trying out Fluent NHibernate 2.12 with System.Data.SQLite (ver 1.0.74.0 with .NET4 x64).
When trying to create my session factory I get the following error (innermost exception):

> The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly
>   System.Data.SQLite could not be found. Ensure that the assembly
>   System.Data.SQLite is located in the application directory or in the
>   Global Assembly Cache. If the assembly is in the GAC, use
>    element in the application configuration file to
>   specify the full name of the assembly.

Tried what was already suggested
my app.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>    
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" >
      <probing privatePath="Lib\NHibernate;Lib\Castle;Lib\SQLite"></probing>
      <qualifyAssembly
        partialName="System.Data.SQLite"
        fullName="System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.74.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and My private probing path contains the correct files (already checked that)
anyone has a clue?

Comment: Are you referencing the SQLLite DLL in your project?

Comment: can you look at the .net-assembly-resolve-log with Fuslogvw.exe? there you can see where he searches for sqllite and if there are any problems loading it

Answer (score 0):

I just recently set up fluent nhibernate with SQLite for unit tests so here are some tips I can give you.
If you are debugging with Visual Studio 2010 you will need to use SQLite 32 bit sadly.  There is a known bug that should be included with the next release of visual studio when you try to include 64 bit assemblies.
Other than that might I suggest you make sure you have included the following entries in your web config.

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

PS found a reference to the bug
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556670/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-when-referencing-a-64-bit-assembly